# Apply select2 with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want add select2 to tag `<select id="test" class="select2"></select>` dynamically. E.g

```
<select id="test" class="select2"></select>

<button onclick="applySelect2()">Click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function applySelect2() {
    //code witch will aplly select2 for <select id="test" class="select2"></select>
    //Please help
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "apply select2"? Add some options to the `<select>`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/276/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the jQuery library, than something like this should help:

```
<select id="test" class="select2"></select>

<button id="myButton">Click me</button>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery(function($) { // DOM READY
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        $("#test").select2();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Or similar to your example:

```
 jQuery(function($) { // DOM READY

     function applySelect2() {
         //code
     }

    $('#myButton').click(function(){
       applySelect2();
    });

 });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/276/ can you write code to function applySelect2(); which will do this magic?

Comment: @Darius did you read my answer and tried my suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/278/

Answer (score -1):

you mean this?

```
function applySelect2() {
   $(".select2").select2();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry but I only want to answer his question, and I thought that's was the answer he was looking for, I didn't intend to critique or request some more clarification.

Comment: You should then edit your answer to make it look clearer, and add some explanation to it, to make it easier to understand.

Comment: How does this add anything that the selected answer does not already address?